# SSHTunnelForwarder not ending after querying remote database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, ssh-tunnel

After successfully connecting to a remote mysql db via sshtunnelforwarder and executing a query with help of sqlalchemy, sshtunnelforwarder server does not stop.

I have tried engine.dispose() after running the query to see if it finishes, but it does not. it only stops if no query is processed and using engine.dispose()

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (remote_ip, 22),
    ssh_username="sshuser",
    ssh_password="sshpwd",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1','3307')
)
server.start()

engine = create_engine('mysql://dbuser:dbpwd@127.0.0.1:3307/dbname')
session = Session(engine)

rs = session.execute('select count(distinct col1) from table1')
for r in rs:
    print(r[0])

print('it gets here')
engine.dispose()
server.stop()
print('Finished!')
```

I am expecting the code to finish and print 'Finsihed!' but the server won't stop, when i comment the query line it does finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not closing the session, so the connection is not returned to the pool held by the engine, so dispose does not dispose of it.

Comment: just tried session.close() after session.dispose(), but also with no luck, thank you anyways.

Comment: Sessions don't have a "dispose" method, so I take it you mean after `engine.dispose()`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I meant engine.dispose()

Comment: Hmm, connections should really close, if the pool they belonged to has been disposed of when you close the session, but just for the heck of it, try closing before disposing?

Comment: I just tried that, and it does work in that order, thank you very much Ilja. Awesome

Answer (score 4):

[Ilja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%c3%a4) pointed me in the right direction on this issue, added session.close() before disposing the engine and it worked well

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (remote_ip, 22),
    ssh_username="sshuser",
    ssh_password="sshpwd",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1','3307')
)
server.start()

engine = create_engine('mysql://dbuser:dbpwd@127.0.0.1:3307/dbname')
session = Session(engine)

rs = session.execute('select count(distinct col1) from table1')
for r in rs:
    print(r[0])

session.close()
engine.dispose()
print('it gets here')
server.stop()
print('Finished!')
```